# Consumer key for Microsoft Access Control Service auth provider?

Tags: community

What would I provide for the "Consumer Key" field for configuring an Auth. Provider if I am using Microsoft's Graph API to register my new app? I'm assuming my consumer secret is the equivalent to the 'client_secret' in the Graph API [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview), however for the consumer key, I'm not sure if that would be the authentication or refresh token that I generate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more that I look at this the more that I think the issue you're facing is that you have a connected app set up and you're trying to provide the information from the connected app to your third party partner. Which I believe is backwards.

The documentation you provided has a link to a more detailed explanation in the left panel ([this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user))

This document says that you have to set up an app on the MS side and that MS provides you with a secret. When you attempt to authenticate this is the secret you need to provide. Their documentation doesn't show anything about generating or requiring a key so I believe the answer to your question is **You don't need to provide the consumer key, you need to provide the secret that Microsoft gives you, not the one SF gives you.**.

That being said, it seems that while you are using sf to make the callout, the issue does not actually exist on the SF side. **You should attempt to contact support for the Microsoft Graph API for further assistance.**

Comment: Thanks gNerb. I actually found another document that didn't directly name Microsoft, but it contained the translation from MS to SF that I needed: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm